# Local GPS not working on glass through GDK

Tags: android, gps, locationmanager, google-glass, google-gdk

The GDK developer guide states:

> Local providers obtain location data from the Glass hardware such as GPS_PROVIDER and NETWORK_PROVIDER.

However this doesn't seem to be the case. I tried logging all available providers with:

```
Log.d("LocationDebug", mLocationManager.getAllProviders().toString());
```

The result is:

> [remote_gps, remote_network, network, passive]

So no local GPS. If I try anyway with the following code:

```
mLocationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, this, null);
```

The app crashes and the following gets logged:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: provider=gps

Comment: Do you need to add any permissions to your app? In your manifest?

Comment: My manifest file has android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, and android.permission.INTERNET

Comment: Are you connected to MyGlass when doing this?

Comment: Need to be connected to smartphone/MyGlass for location, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343373/location-on-google-glass

Comment: I don't have MyGlass (I've got an iPhone). Although the quote from the developer guide implies that you can use the GPS chip directly on glass without getting remote data from an android device

Comment: Yeah, I was wondering if maybe being connected to MyGlass would give you different options. I'll try this a little later on my Glass and see if I get the same results.

Comment: Well somehow the navigation app handles local GPS without a MyGlass connection (with the GPS_ENABLE_LOCAL labs feature enabled). However having that enabled still doesn't change the results in my app

Comment: The documentation has been updated to clarify the best practices for location on Glass. Currently, Glass gets GPS information from remote providers through MyGlass, and because the list of location providers is dynamic, you should use the Criteria-based approach or the all-providers approach.

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [location and sensors developer guide](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/location-sensors/index), you should avoid referring to specific location providers, such as `GPS_PROVIDER` by name. Instead, use a `Criteria`-based approach or iterate over *all* location providers to ensure that you include the "remote" providers that retrieve locations from a Bluetooth tethered device running the MyGlass companion app. This will get you the most reliable location information.